# It is possible to use this 'INSERT INTO' statement in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO PHOENIX_AUDITTRAIL SET
audit_module = 'Location Master',
audit_message = 'Delete location',
datecreated = NOW(),
author = '".$_SESSION['username']."',
status = '".ADT_NOTICE."';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the standard way to phrase this is:

```
INSERT INTO PHOENIX_AUDITTRAIL(audit_module, audit_message, datecreated, author, status)
    select 'Location Master', 'Delete location', NOW(), '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".ADT_NOTICE."'
    from dual
```

However, in Oracle, I think you would use `sysdate` instead of `now()`:

```
INSERT INTO PHOENIX_AUDITTRAIL(audit_module, audit_message, datecreated, author, status)
    select 'Location Master', 'Delete location', sysdate, '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".ADT_NOTICE."'
    from dual
```

Except for the date variables and the `from dual`, this is standard SQL syntax.

Comment: Ok tq.. but i had using that 'insert statement' by using php and mysql, and it worked perfectly. i new in oracle, thanks for that info